# Unwind Navigation Controller on when switching tabs

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My setup is follows: I have a TabBarController at the root initial view and the following tabs: TabViewController1 and MoreMenuViewController. The More Menu View controller has an embedded UIVNavigationController which has a button that pushes  SettingsViewController into view.

```
UITabbarController -> UINavigationController -> TabViewController1
UITabbarController -> UINavigationController -> MoreMenuViewController -> SettingsViewController
```

Now, assume I am in the SettingsViewController. I click the tab to go to TabViewController1. When I click the tab to go to MoreMenuViewController I am shown SettingsViewController instead. I'd like it to show MoreMenuViewController on tab switch.

I am using iOS8 and XCode6 with Storyboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MoreMenuViewController` you can implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method like this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Moreover you need to set `MoreMenuViewController` to be delegate of `UITabBarControllerDelegate` (for example in `viewDidLoad` method) via:

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Would I do this in the Settings View Controller instead on ViewWillDisappear or something? Shouldn't the unwind occur when I switch away?

Edit: Just added "[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO] to my viewWillDisappear method on SettingsViewController and it seems to have the desired effect. Thanks!

Comment: `UITabBarController` is not deallocating its `UIViewController`'s when user switches tabs. So, `UINavigationController`'s are preserving state between switching tabs. So if you are in `SettingsViewController` and go to other tab, `SettingsViewController` is not popped from its `UINavigationController`. Glad to help.